# Some objects don't draw on some devices

Tags: android, text, opengl-es, rendering

I use OpenGL ES 2.0 in order to draw Square objects like from this tutorial:
developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html
and to draw text like from this tutorial:
fractiousg.blogspot.com/2012/04/rendering-text-in-opengl-on-android.html

```
    d1.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    d2.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    d3.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    d4.draw(mMVPMatrix);


    p1.draw(mMVPMatrix);
    if(punkty>0)
    p2.draw(mMVPMatrix);

    koala.draw(mMVPMatrix);



    punktyString = String.valueOf(punkty);
    glText.begin( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, mVPMatrix );
    glText.drawC(punktyString, width/2, height/2);
    glText.end();  <i>
```

To draw square object I use mMVPMatrix. To draw text I use mVPMatrix.

onSurfaceChanged:

```
    float ratio = (float) width / height;


    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -1, 1, -1 / ratio, 1 / ratio, 1, 10);

    int useForOrtho = Math.min(width, height);

    //TODO: Is this wrong?
    Matrix.orthoM(mVMatrix, 0,
            -useForOrtho / 2,
            useForOrtho / 2,
            -useForOrtho / 2,
            useForOrtho / 2, 0.1f, 100f);



    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 3, 7); </i>
```

onDrawFrame:

```
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
```

On most devices app works well:

http://prntscr.com/75ucsf

But on some devices app works like this:

http://prntscr.com/75ucle

Only text is rendered, Square objects aren't rendered. 
What should I do to render both Square objects and text on all devices?

Ask me if you need more informations.

Comment: What are the position of the quads you are drawing?

Comment: Also you have way too many matrices, what's the difference between mVMatrix and mViewMatrix? And mProjMatrix / mProjectionMatrix?

Comment: @Jerem 4 quads have stable positions.(d1,d2,d3,d4) Other quads change their position in every frame by those methods. 
 `public void moveX (float x) {
         for(int i= 0; i <12; i =i+3)
            coords[i]=coords[i]+ x; 
         vertexBuffer.put(coords);
         vertexBuffer.position(0);
    }`

    `public void moveY(float y) {
        for(int i=1; i<12; i =i+3)
            coords[i] = coords[i] + y;
        vertexBuffer.put(coords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);
    } `  http://prntscr.com/75wh6u